# Application of Conditionals to Sets

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Our biggest issue is how to make sense of conditionals in the Truth Table Format, and applying them to understand sets. We tried coming up with an easy example in excel for our own purpose.

Let $P:= x\gt 2$, and $Q: = x^2 > 4$.

The screenshot is uploaded via imgur:

[image]

The red highlighted figures are incorrect because the **converse and inverse** are supposed to be equivalent, and **contrapositives** of conditionals are supposed to be equivalent to the conditional. However, we can't seem to make sense of this.

This is for a study group. Let us know!

Thanks!

Comment: You can't do number theory with sentential logic. Choose different examples for $P$ and $Q$.

Comment: @aduh, why can't you do number theory with sentential logic?

Comment: It doesn't have enough expressive power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't** fully represent the information in propositional logic (aka, sentential logic).

What you need to fully capture the information is to use predicate logic with quantifiers:

E.g. Let $P(x)$ denote $x\geq 2$. Then $\lnot P(x)$ will be, essentially, $x\lt 2$.

Let $Q(x)$ denote $x^2 \geq 4$, so that $\lnot Q(x)$ becomes $x^2\lt 4$.

Let's make the universe of discourse the set of the non-negative real numbers, $\mathbb R_{x\geq 0}$.

Then you might say something like:

$$\forall x\Big((P(x)\rightarrow Q(x))\land ((\lnot P(x)) \rightarrow (\lnot Q(x))\Big)\tag 1$$

This can be adapted for *all* reals, but you'd need $P(x): (x \leq -2)$ or $(x\geq 2)$, so $\lnot P(x): -2 < x < 2$.

Likewise you can extend $Q(x)$ over the domain of real numbers: Let $Q(x): x^2 \geq 4$, while $\lnot (Q(x)): 0\leq x^2\lt4$

Then $(1)$ holds as well, given the modified domain and predicates.

Comment: This answered my original question perfectly. Does it mean there are pitfalls to sentential logic, or it is predicate logic with quantifiers an extension of sentential logic?

Comment: Most things in number theory and mathematics in general, are much easier to state in predicate + quantifier logics.  Even something as simple as $2 \gt 1$ can be more accurately expressed with a predicate $G(x,y):= x>y$, becoming $G(2,1)$. In Sentential logic, you'd need a proposition $P: = 2>1$. And could only express "that P".  You'd need a proposition for every pair of numbers you want to compare. At any rate, predicate logic with quantifiers requires an understanding of sentential logic. So sentential logic is not thrown out.

Comment: To be completely honest, @gswamibu, I cannot understand the down-votes you received; you showed effort, you were clear in your question; I feel compelled to apologize for having to experience that.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's fine. I was more worried about my understanding of the problem than the down-votes, though I expected this question would have received more up-votes from beginners like me. Nobody in class could figure out this issue until the teacher was available. However, to critique myself, the title of the question could have been more descriptive. Not sure I have the vocabulary to make it such. How would you re-title this?

Answer (score 0):

Recall that 
$$P\to Q$$
is always true, unless $P$ is true, and $Q$ is false.
Thus 
$$\lnot Q\to \lnot P$$
is always true, unless $\lnot Q$ is true, and $\lnot P$ is false. But this is indeed equivalent to the above.

Of course none of these is equivalent to 
$$Q\to P,$$
as this is always true, unless $Q$ is true, and $P$ is false.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that according to @aduh's comment, i can't use number theory with sententials. Do you agree? If so, why?